# Objective-c Extracting multiple variables from Big string (performance improvements)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I need to extract multiple variables to array from big string 0,5mb .This script is working when input string is smaller ~50kb and around 100 items to find. but target is around 7k items to extract from 0.5mb string. When there is less than 300 items it works. but finish after few sec. But if more im getting issue:

```
 Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x321f9614> { count = 1, contents = "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x321f986c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
```

Code

```
                NSUInteger count = 0, length = [dataString length];
                NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
                while(range.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    range = [dataString rangeOfString: @"userID_X" options:0 range:range];
                    if(range.location != NSNotFound)
                    {
                        range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                NSLog(@"Count:%i",count);
                realTokens = [NSMutableArray new];
                realIds = [NSMutableArray new];

                for (int gg=0; gg<count-1; gg++) {
                    NSArray *realidtemp;
                    NSArray *realtokentemp;
                    realidtemp = [[[dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"userID_X"]objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
                    realtokentemp = [[[dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"userToken"]objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
                    NSString *checkTkn = realtokentemp[0];
                    NSString *checkId = realidtemp[0];
                    if (![checkTkn containsString:@"EMPTY"] && ![checkId containsString:@"EMPTY"]) {
                        [realTokens addObject:checkTkn];
                        [realIds addObject:checkId];
                        NSString *fix1 = @"userToken";
                        NSString *fix2 = @"userID_X";
                        fix1 = [fix1 stringByAppendingString:checkTkn];
                        fix2 = [fix2 stringByAppendingString:checkId];
                        dataString  = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:fix1 withString:@"EMPTY"];
                        dataString  = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:fix2 withString:@"EMPTY"];
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You can try looking at the documentation of `NSScanner`. It should be the best class to parse a string

Answer (score 0):

You perform many operations with a runtime proportional to the number of characters. That's something you need to avoid. You are also creating a huge number of huge autoreleased strings. Each time you call stringByReplacing... you create a new 0.5MB string. On an iPhone with 1GB RAM, 2,000 calls fill your RAM completely but you will crash earlier. componentsSeparatedByString is just as bad.

Create an NSMutableString for the result, and only add the pieces that you want to add. And please please please don't ask how to do that.